# Do NPC's that are killed in the dungeon move in?

Tags: terraria

I was exploring the dungeon after defeating skeletron and I found the engineer and the goblin NPC. Shortly after, they were killed while still in the dungeon. Will they still move in despite being killed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. They will respawn like NPCs killed anywhere else assuming you freed them (talked to them) before they died.